# How to use innerhtml function in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

Hi i am current working on a task in which if the size of characters is more than 200 than it will substring the characters more than 200.if i give a simple text than it is working fine but if i provide any link into it then it consider the tag also like anchor tag etc. i want just to get innerHTML is it poosible in JSp? or there is another alternative way for it here is my code.

```
<c:set var="finaldescription" value="" scope="page" />
<c:set var="description" value="${properties.description}" scope="page"/>
<c:set var="descriptionLength" value="${fn:length(string1)}" scope="page" />
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:length(description) gt 200}">
        <c:set var="finaldescription" value="${fn:substring(description, 0, 200)}..." scope="page" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="finaldescription" value="${description}" scope="page" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: I believe you somehow completely missed the fact that JSP is merely a HTML/CSS/JS code producer. So whatever you'd like the produced HTML/CSS/JS to look like (as visible via rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser), you can easily generate that with JSP. This definitely also covers JS code.

Comment: yes i can but i dnt want to use javascript.i think u didn't get my requirement. suppose i want to show only 15 characters 12345678901234  but i make anyone of them a link suppose 2 then it will show only 12 because after one it will take as 1<a href="abc.com">2</a> and i want to take it as only 2 nt <a> tag

Comment: have you tried properties.description.substring(0,200) ?